# Set hidden input value in Selenium?

Tags: html, selenium-ide, hidden-field

We have hidden input fields on our form and we need Selenium to set the value of those fields.  What is the best way to set the value of hidden inputs via Selenium IDE?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Easiest way I could find:

Command: runScript

Value:

```
javascript{this.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().document.getElementById('hiddenElementId').value='TheValue'}
```

Comment: +1 good answer, even easier with a js library (if the page under test uses one), e.g. jquery:`$('#hiddenEl').val('foo')`

Comment: I couldn't get the jquery one to work. jQuery is in the page. Can you post the entire string you have in your Selenium runScript value?

Comment: You might want to simply put it within the appropriate domready functionality, e.g. `$(function(){// on domready
$('#hiddenEl').val('foo');});`

Comment: A bit late, but how do I achieve this with java? TIA!!

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party...

When you use the IDE, you can add the command **type** with target **id=yourID** and value **field value**, this seems to work.

Copy the text below and paste it in the IDE to try it out

```
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=yourID</td>
    <td>field value</td>
</tr>
```

This seems to work for me (Selenium 2.9.1)