# Read a hidden value in a div using Selenium Python binding

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

**Issue:** How can you read a value in a nested `<div>`?

**Situation:** I am testing the registration on our web site. In order to complete the process, the user will need to enter the captcha. Using a helper class (on our dev server) we can display (hidden) the current captcha. I need to grab that and save it to be used by a .send_keys function (that part is the easy part). I have no code to share with what I am using, as I am not even sure where to jump in.

Well, I have this, but this is obviously not the answer:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("capchta").send_keys("foobar")
```

With above, I can send a key value (seen as "foobar"). I just need to replace "foobar" with a string that I read in the `value=XXX`

Here is the HTML code with the captcha, represented with the `value=XXXX`.

```
<div id="code_area">
     <p id="captcha_blurb">Please enter the security code below</p>
     <div id="capchta_area">
     <img id="secuity_icon" src="/img3/Secuity-Icon.png">
     <img id="security-image" src="data:image/png;==">
     <input id="current_captcha" type="hidden" value="XXXX">
     <input id="capchta" class="reg_form_input" value="" name="code" placeholder="Enter Security Code" title=" Please Enter These Characters." onblur="removeInputInfoBox('reg_box');" onfocus="addInputInfoBox('#capchta','#capchta_area', 'reg_box');">
</div>
```

Comment: Are you just trying to change the value of a hidden input?

Comment: No. Just read it. So I can use it. (See below)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you need to execute JS to get the hidden input's value.

You can use `get_attribute` to the value attribute

> [get_attribute(name)](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute)

So in your case, try:

```
captcha_value = driver.find_element_by_id("current_captcha").get_attribute("value")
driver.find_element_by_id("capchta").send_keys(captcha_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327027/how-to-set-value-of-a-hidden-input-with-selenium) Selenium can't interact with hidden elements. You're going to need to execute javascript to change the value for you; which is still a perfectly valid and accepted way of using Selenium.

Comment: It states, "Selenium WebDriver cannot interact with hidden elements, it can only find them" I am not trying to interact with it. Just find it. If I can find the `value=XXXX`, then I can capture it to a string and `.send_keys(XXXX)`, exactly what I want.