# Extracting hidden element in Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, captcha, recaptcha

I have an element of type `hidden` in an iframe. I am wondering if there would be any way to get this value as I am using selenium. More specifically it is a captcha field. I've tried pulling it with something along the lines of

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_bin_path)
driver.get('http://websitehere.com')
print driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="recaptcha-token"]').text
```

but because of it's hidden nature it returns nothing.

Below is a snippet of the source.
Highlighted is the string of interest. (value)

[image: source]

Comment: You may have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500711/read-a-hidden-value-in-a-div-using-selenium-python-binding) question. Maybe it could help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
driver.switch_to_frame('undefined')
token_value = driver.find_element_by_id('recaptcha-token').get_attribute('value')
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

[Moving between windows and frames](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames).

Comment: As a bonus, would you know if I could repeat the step after captcha solve? After solving, a new tag appears with matching id inside of the #document in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 4):

Use this method

```
hidden_text = element.get_attribute("textContent")
```