# Unable to enter text in textfield in Selenium java

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, hidden-field

Below is the relevant snippet of HTML code :

```
         </td>                                   
         <td valign=top bgcolor="#dcdcdc" class="camp">
          <script>Oblog()</script>ID <br>


        <input type="text" name="idClnt" size="14" maxlength="11" value='' class="cat" onchange="Camp(this);resetPreScore();" onKeyPress="if (event.keyCode == 13){EnterData();}">
```

I used the below line of code to enter data

```
driver.findElement(By.name("idClnt")).sendKeys("10000057W");
```

I am unable to enter data in the text field . It gives the below error :

"Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not displayed (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) "

But the element does not seem to be invisible and i am able to locate the element by using below code :

```
      List<WebElement> ele = driver.findElements(By.name("idClnt"));

             System.out.println(ele);
```

It gives the output :

```
 [[[InternetExplorerDriver: internet explorer on WINDOWS (f319ec27-9201-4536-80a1-fe89689ebe83)] -> name: idClnt], [[InternetExplorerDriver: internet explorer on WINDOWS (f319ec27-9201-4536-80a1-fe89689ebe83)] -> name: idClnt], [[InternetExplorerDriver: internet explorer on WINDOWS (f319ec27-9201-4536-80a1-fe89689ebe83)] -> name: idClnt]]
```

Kindly suggest how would i be able to enter data in the text field

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use something like?

```
driver.findElement(By.name("idClnt")).sendKeys("whatever you want to type");
```

Why are you using list here, if you just want to type data in the input box?

Answer (score 0):

1) In order to check visibility of element you should use `isDisplayed` method:

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class=cat]"));  
System.out.println(el.isDisplayed());
```

2) Enter text:

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class=cat]"));
el.sendKeys("SO the best!");
```

3) If you want to set the `value` for hidden `input` try following (in more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/16327185/2517622):

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class=cat]"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value = arguments[1];", el, "SO the best!");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply !! I used the isDisplayed method and it throws the result as false implying that element is invisible . So i would be needing a way to enter data in hidden field ?

Comment: Thanks for the response !! But it does not seem to work also the program just terminates without any error . I tried one of the methods given in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858366/how-to-type-some-text-in-hidden-field-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java?rq=1) . Using that method gives me an error "Element must not be hidden, disabled or read-only" .